# Delay systemd service if file exist

Tags: systemd, services

I want to delay the start of a service if a file exists (instead of fail the service if the file exist, as with `ConditionPathExists=`) but did not find anything in unit [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Is it technically possible with systemd ?
How ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**using just one unit**

Put `TimeoutStartSec=infinity` in the unit file and configure `ExecStart=` with a script like

```
#! /bin/bash

TIMEOUT=1000

test -f /path/to/testfile && sleep "$TIMEOUT"

exec /path/to/service/binary plus arguments
```

This cannot be done (in a useful way) with `ExecStartPre=`, see `man systemd.service`:

> Note that ExecStartPre= may not be used to start long-running processes. All processes forked off by processes invoked via ExecStartPre= will be killed before the next service process is run.

**using a helper unit**

If you want to do this with systemd "alone" then you can create a helper unit `check_and_wait.target`. This one gets the entries

```
# check_and_wait.target
[Unit]
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
ConditionPathExists=/path/to/testfile
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 1000
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

The main unit gets these entries:

```
Wants=check_and_wait.target
After=check_and_wait.target
```

Comment: Surely it can use `ExecStartPre`, just move `binary` into `ExecStart`.  What goes wrong?

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible with systemd and necessarily require a shell script (bash or other) ?

Comment: @Zulgrib As usual there are several possibilities. I have added another to my answer.

Comment: You can use ExecStartPre (since it's not sleeping forever) ... methinks...

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell `ConditionPathExists=` does not put the unit into a "failed" state. `ConditionPathExists=` only skips the unit.

> Unit files may also include a number of Condition…= and Assert…=
>   settings. Before the unit is started, systemd will verify that the
>   specified conditions are true. If not, the starting of the unit will
>   be (mostly silently) skipped. Failing conditions will not result in
>   the unit being moved into the "failed" state.

One way I found to delay the start of a unit, based on the existence of a file, is to test for the file with `ExecStartPre=`, then `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=`. This does put the unit into a failure state, but it will keep retrying until success. For example:

```
[Service]
# Should cause failure if file exists
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/test ! -f afile
ExecStart=mycommand

# Restart on failure. Keep trying to create backup.
RestartSec=10m
Restart=on-failure
```

Comment: Works without the negation to wait for a config file to be created!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=bash -c "while [ -f /path/to/file ]; do sleep 1; done"
ExecStart=your_command
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that this would inhibit starting the service until the file disappears, not delay it for a fixed amount of time if the file is present (which seems to be what the OP wands).